# Transaction between two session beans in ejb3

Tags: ejb-3.0, stateless-session-bean, entity-bean

I have three tables server_detail, server_group, server_group_mappping and the entity classes as below. (have not given the full code details)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "server_detail")
public class ServerBean implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "server_id")
private Integer ServerId;

@Column(name = "name")
private String serverName;
....
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "server_group")
public class ServerGroupBean implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "group_id")
private Integer groupId;

@Column(name = "name")
private String groupName;
....
}

@Entity
@IdClass(GroupMapPK.class)
@Table(name = "server_group_mapping")
public class ServerGroupMapBean implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Column(name = "group_id")
private Integer groupId;
@Id
@Column(name = "server_id")
private Integer serverId;
....
}
```

Each Entity Bean class having one wrapper class, to manage operations on entity bean as below

```
@Stateless
@Local
public class ServerClient implements ServerLocal {
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

public ServerClient() {
}
public ServerBean create(java.lang.String name) {
    ServerBean bean = new ServerBean(name);
    em.persist(bean);
    return bean;
}
public ServerBean update(ServerBean bean){
    return (em.contains(bean) ? bean : em.merge(bean));
}
public void remove(ServerBean bean) {
    em.remove(em.contains(bean) ? bean : em.merge(bean));
}


@Stateless
@Local
public class ServerGroupClient implements ServerGroupLocal {
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

public ServerGroupClient() {
}
public ServerGroupBean create(java.lang.Integer name) {
    ServerGroupBean bean = new ServerGroupBean(name);
    em.persist(bean);
    return bean;
}
public ServerGroupBean update(ServerGroupBean bean){
    return (em.contains(bean) ? bean : em.merge(bean));
}
public void remove(ServerGroupBean bean) {
    em.remove(em.contains(bean) ? bean : em.merge(bean));
}


@Stateless
@Local
public class ServerGroupMapClient implements ServerGroupMapLocal {
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

public ServerGroupMapClient() {
}
public ServerGroupMapBean create(java.lang.Integer serverId,java.lang.Integer groupId ) {
    ServerGroupMapBean bean = new ServerBean(serverId, groupId);
    em.persist(bean);
    return bean;
}
public ServerBean update(ServerBean bean){
    return (em.contains(bean) ? bean : em.merge(bean));
}
public void remove(ServerBean bean) {
    em.remove(em.contains(bean) ? bean : em.merge(bean));
}
```

I am using MYSQL (innoDB Engine) for the tables and the their relation mapping amound the tables.

Now, I have GroupManager session Bean class, which maintains the server_group and server_group_mapping table transactions. When ever i create server group and the members, i have to do following transaction.

```
 1. First, add group id and group name to server_group table
 2. Second, map groupid with server id in server_group_mapping table
```

Following is the code.

```
@Stateless
@Local
public class GroupManagerBean implements GroupManagerLocal {
    @Resource
    private SessionContext context;

    private static GroupLocal GroupLocal;
    private static GroupMapLocal GroupMapLocal;
    public GroupManagerBean() {
        GroupLocal = ServiceLocator.getGroupLocal();
        smscMapLocal = ServiceLocator.getGroupMapLocal();
    }
    public void addGroup(GroupBean bean, Integer serverId){
        group = GroupLocal.create(bean.getGroupName()); ---> 1
        ...
        GroupMapLocal.create(group.getGroupId(), serverId); ----> 2
        }
```

ServiceLocator class is the location where can i lookup all my beans.
Bydefault, in ejb3 transaction attribute is required. if i execute addGroup() method. m getting following exception.

```
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: EntityManager must be access within a transaction
at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.Ejb3TxPolicy.handleInCallerTx(Ejb3TxPolicy.java:115)
at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInCallerTx(TxPolicy.java:130)
at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:194)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:76)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.java:186)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:41)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.ejb3.asynchronous.AsynchronousInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousInterceptor.java:106)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.ejb3.BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.invoke(BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.java:67)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.aspects.currentinvocation.CurrentInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationInterceptor.java:67)
at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
at org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionSpecContainer.invoke(SessionSpecContainer.java:219)
at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.handler.ProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:261)
....
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: EntityManager must be access within a transaction
at org.jboss.jpa.deployment.ManagedEntityManagerFactory.verifyInTx(ManagedEntityManagerFactory.java:155)
at org.jboss.jpa.tx.TransactionScopedEntityManager.persist(TransactionScopedEntityManager.java:186)
at com.example.GroupClient.create(GroupClient.java:37)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

As per the error persistence managers(GroupClient and GroupMapClient) is out of our transaction scope. I would like to know, how can i make the transaction happen completely while injecting the persistence managers into the transaction scope?

Answer (score 0):

Refer below link for details.

https://developer.jboss.org/message/525521